# Stored Procedure call in JavaScript is saying that their are too many arguments, however I am passing in the correct number

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am calling a stored procedure within an API, creating a simple registration/login system.

```
db.executeQueryWithParams(config.storedProcedures.CheckEmail, email, (err, result) => { 
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("succeeded - ", result);
        ;
    }
});
```

This "ExecuteQueryWithParams" is a standard function that I have been handed that is used in conjunction with the database. I have a working version of it elsewhere in my code where I insert the user information into my database, so I know that it isn't an issue with the function itself. For clarity, this is the function:

```
executeQueryWithParams(storedProc, params, callback) {
    var request = this.getRequest();
    for (var key in params) {
        request.input(key, params[key]);
    }
    this.executeRequest(request, storedProc, callback);
}
```

This is the stored procedure that is being called:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CheckEmail]
    @email varchar(255)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * from [TABLE] WHERE email = @email
END
```

However when the Stored Procedure is called, I am getting an error that I am passing too many arguments into the procedure. I am getting the email parameter from the API request, and I am ONLY passing in the email address, e.g. "example.email@gmail.com"

Specifically the error says "RequestError: Procedure or function sp_CheckEmail has too many arguments specified."

I am confident that I am only passing the one required argument into the stored procedure, but I cannot figure out why it is telling me that I have too many.

I have tried different formats, making sure that it wasn't due to the email address or any special characters that may be causing the issue. Even if I just use a simple string like a name it is still giving me this issue. I have also tested by creating more arguments, up to 5, to see if that would somehow satisfy the error that I am having.

Comment: It would be useful to see ALL the stored proceedure, at least all the part with the parameters that you are using

Comment: is it mysql or sql-server?

Comment: "`for (var key in params)`" what is `email`?

Comment: Based on the `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to appears to be SQL Server, *not* MySQL. You also omit the `CREATE`/`ALTER` clause for your procedures definition. Finally, the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Answer (score 0):

`for...in` on a string (`email`) is your problem here

```js
const params = "test@test.com"
for (var key in params) {
  console.log(key, params[key]);
}
```

Your code will be trying to ad one parameter to your stored proc for every character in your email.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` is going to loop through all the characters in the string. Instead pass in an object with a property called `email`

```js
db.executeQueryWithParams(config.storedProcedures.CheckEmail, {email: email}, (err, result) => { 
...
```